# How to make a <li> using keydown of enter and .appendChild in JS?

Tags: javascript, list, keydown, appendchild

I have an input text field I'd like to create a

in my  when enter is pressed.
I'm not sure where I went wrong in my code.

Here's a snippet of the HTML I'm editing

```
`<div class="day" id="monday"><div class="span"><h3 class="day-title">Monday</h3></div>
<input type="text" class="input" id="input-area">
<ul id='list'></ul>
</div>`
```

And the JS I've tried to implement

```
`function addItemToList() {
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const input = document.querySelector('input');
        const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.innerHTML = input.value;
    }
})
};`
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: why is addEventListener() call is inside addItemToList()? have you call addItemToList()?

Answer (score 0):

this works just fine

```html
<script>
  const input = document.querySelector('input');
  const list = document.querySelector('ul');

  input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode !== 13) return;

    e.preventDefault();
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerHTML = input.value;
    list.appendChild(item);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I copied what you posted and tried it in my code and had no result; could the issue be because I have multiple instances of input and <ul>? There are 7 inputs and <ul>s, each labeled similarly except for the fact that the ID is different for each day of the week.
Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: document.querySelector only select the first occurence